# How to delete photos posted using Google+ API

Tags: google-plus, picasa

I have successfully uploaded photos to Google+ via media.inset and the activities.insert and have the id of the photo.

But I can't seem to find any informant about deletes! If I manually delete the photo from Google+ website, I see that the same id is submitted for delete.

Does Google not allow deletes via API? That would be very weird.

**UPDATE:**
Google Issue Tracker Link: [Issue #1065](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=1065&q=remove&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Component%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

Answer (score 1):

You cant do it though the Google+ api its not supported but ...

I would try going though the Picasa api. I haven't tried this its just an idea [Delete Photos](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#DeletePhotos)

Google+ photos are Picasa photo's so this leads me to believe that you should be able to delete it though the other api.

**Update**:  IMO its a good idea. I would add it as a feature request.  Google-plus-platform [Issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list)  If you do add it post the link and I will add my start to it as well see if we can get it some attention.

Comment: Ok I will check it out and let everyone know. This overlap between Picassa and Google+ is confusing!

Comment: I've tried. Sending all the right requests... I'm stuck with Cross Origin problems. It seems like the Picasa API doesn't allow cross origin DELETE requests.

Comment: add it as a feature request :)

Comment: Hi. I've created the issue ticket. Link above. Pls add your 2 cents.